# Error while accessing local file using selenium webdriver

Tags: python, xml, selenium-webdriver

I am having an issue which I tried to reproduce locally.

I have an XML file and when I open it `chrome webdriver` with url like: `http://localhost:63342/Testing_Prj/EXPORT.xml` the **driver.page_source** working fine. Alternately if I open the same file using url like: `file:///E:/Testing_Prj/EXPORT.xml` the **driver.page_source** and other properties gives **timeout error**.

The original issue is when I click on (Generate) button, a new tab opens with dynamic url and opens the dynamically generated xml data.

After switch_to that window_handler I am unable to do any activity, like page_source, execute_script, etc.

**EXPORT.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<teachers>
    <teacher>
        <name>Sam Davies</name>
        <age>35</age>
        <subject>Maths</subject>
    </teacher>
    <teacher>
        <name>Cassie Stone</name>
        <age>24</age>
        <subject>Science</subject>
    </teacher>
    <teacher>
        <name>Derek Brandon</name>
        <age>32</age>
        <subject>History</subject>
    </teacher>
</teachers>
```

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Opening the local file as below

```
driver.get("file:///E:/Testing_Prj/EXPORT.xml")
```

you should add `file:///` to start of file path

Comment: that was my typo mistake. Updated the url, But that one is for sample, the original is dynamically generated url with dynamic xml.